# Recursively invoke function in Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux-toolkit

I need help with Redux.
I have been studying JS, React and Redux for some time, specifically `slices`, but I can't get this to work right.
I want to have a dynamic menu in my app, so that it initially loads from the slice, but can be modified from actions that can be executed by the user.
At the moment I have something like this (obviously simplified to show it here)

```
const menu = createSlice({
    name: 'menu',
    initialState: {
        selectedSideMenuItem: 'dashboard',
        sideMenuIsOpen: false,
        sideMenu: [
            {
                id: 'dashboard',
                //...
                children: [
                    {
                        id: 'dashboard-default',
                        //...
                    },
                    {
                        id: 'dashboard-analytics',
                        //...
                    },
                    {
                        id: 'dashboard-kanban',
                        //...
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                id: 'admin',
                //...
                children: [
                    {
                        id: 'admin-crm',
                        //...
                        children: [
                            {
                                id: 'admin-crm-client',
                                //...
                            },
                            {
                                id: 'admin-crm-contract',
                                //...
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        id: 'admin-hr',
                        //...
                        children: [
                            {
                                id: 'admin-hr-department',
                                //...
                            },
                            {
                                id: 'admin-hr-employee',
                                //...
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    //...
                ]
            },
            //...
        ],
    },
    reducers: {
        selectSideMenuItem(state, action) {
            state.selectedSideMenuItem = action.payload;
        },
        setSideMenu(state, action) {
            state.sideMenu = action.payload;
        },
        updateSideMenu(state, action) {
            action.payload.forEach((updItem) => {
                const itemIdx = state.sideMenu.findIndex((menuItem) => menuItem.id === updItem.id);

                if (itemIdx !== -1) {
                    state.sideMenu.splice(itemIdx, 1, updItem);
                } else {
                    // Continue searching for the element recursively
                }
            });
        },
        //...
    }
});

export default menu.reducer;

export const { selectSideMenuItem, setSideMenu, updateSideMenu } = menu.actions;
```

So, basically I need to be able to update it recursively, that is, the `updateSideMenu` function will receive an array of elements in the `payload` that will represent the menu items to be updated, and if for example it receives an element with ID `dashboard`, it should then completely replace the object with that ID, wherever it is inside the menu.
I do not know how to recursively invoke this function `updateSideMenu`, nor what elements to pass in the parameters to achieve the desired effect.